# Get MySQL database structure alter queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I'm working on a version control program, and I would like to implement database structure versioning as well.
Is there a way to get a list of all the queries that have altered the databse structure in any way?

For example I added a column to the 'users' table called 'remember_token'. Is there a way I can get the specific query that was executed on the MySQL server in order to add that column?

Comment: have you looked in the history ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to enable the [mysql query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and then filter on `ALTER` queries or anything you need